# Send Maven output to file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I would like for my maven output (for example during a build) to be written to a file, as the console in Eclipse quickly clogs up. Is there any way I could do this in Eclipse, or do I have to resort to building my project from the command-line using the -DoutputFile option?

Comment: what do you mean by clogs up ? You can extend the console buffer. Personally I do not use Eclipse to run maven commands. I defined some aliases in my shell.

Comment: I didn't know or think about that buffer, stupid, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the Eclipse console buffer, use the max value and you will be fine. Personally I do not use Eclipse to run maven commands. I defined some aliases in my shell. As my comment seems to help I have put it as an answer...